# TortoiseGit: Apply patch as manual changes (without trailing information like Description, Date etc). Possible?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

What I want is when I apply TortoiseGit (TGit) patch, it should not show any linkage. It should show changes as if I have made changes manually (This happens in TSVN because when we apply patch, they are shown as manual changes)

Why I want this is because I need to make additional changes along with patch changes.

Steps I did/doing:

1. Created a TGit patch from a local commit.
2. Then deleted the local repository and re-downloaded the branch from remote.
3. Now applied patch. It shows information of commit like description and date etc. Don't need this. It should show patch changes as manual changes.

Is it possible using TGit?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply a serial patch and then reset the index to the previous commit (as described by [Lex Li](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40363838/3906760)), however, another approach would be to right click on the .patch- or .diff-file and select "Review/apply single patch...". Then TortoiseGitMerge is opened and you can apply and modify the files manually. Afterwards you can commit your all changes.

Comment: Its nice to hear when some one from inside reaches out to help. Appreciate your support. The second one worked for me and worked as I wanted without having to reset any indexes. +1

Answer (score 2):

1. Apply the patch and see it becomes a commit.
2. Go to log view and reset that branch to the previous commit with mixed or soft mode.

Then you get what you want.